# Get Elements from tree at given level

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, tree

I would like to get all integer keys at a given depth/level of a tree.

The solution I tried looks like this:

```
public LinkedList<Integer> keysAtDepth(int depth) {
    return getGivenLevel(depth, root);
}

private  LinkedList<Integer> getGivenLevel(int depth, Node root) {
     LinkedList<Integer> list = new  LinkedList<Integer>();

     if (root == null) {
        return list;
    }

    if (depth == 1) {
        System.out.println(root.key);
        list.add(root.key);
    } else if (depth > 1 ) {
        getGivenLevel(depth-1, root.left); 
        getGivenLevel(depth-1, root.right);
    }

    return list;
}
```

But this is returning me an empty list. The `print` works just fine, but how can I make it work so I get the keys inside my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `list` is being created every time the function is called and the recursive calls are not adding values to the existing `list`, but are creating a new `list` every time. Place the statement `LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();` outside the function and your code will work as expected or you can even pass a `list` reference to the function and add values to that!

Comment: that was it! I am passing the `list` as an extra argument now and it is working just as expexted

Answer (score 1):

As modifying arguments is not a good practice in Java, the minimial side-effect solucion should replace this two lines:

```
   getGivenLevel(depth-1, root.left); 
   getGivenLevel(depth-1, root.right);
```

with:

```
   list.addAll(getGivenLevel(depth-1, root.left)); 
   list.addAll(getGivenLevel(depth-1, root.right));
```